# How to list the files in a sharepoint online directory via powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Hello I am trying to upload a file to my my Sharepoint Site (root directory) via PowerShell.
I can connect to the url but having issues with when trying to upload the file
i have installed Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

when i run the command i get this error

Add-PnPFile : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PnPFile -Path D:\delme\test.xlsx -Folder /
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFile], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.AddFile

Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://ABC123.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/teamsites/os/Directory%20and%20Operating%20Systems/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewpath=%2Fsites%2Fisd%2Fteamsites%2Fos%2FDirectory%20and%20Operating%20Systems%2FForms%2FAllItems.aspx

Add-PnPFile -Path D:\delme\test.xlsx -Folder /

I know I am close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PowerShell below.

```
$siteurl="https://ABC123.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/teamsites/os" 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl
Add-PnPFile -Path D:\delme\test.xlsx -Folder "Directory and Operating Systems"
```

Comment: i need to check with the sharepoint admin cause it is still sayingForbidden. But thanks for the code. I will you know tomorrow

Comment: OK, use the admin user to check if it works, and check the permission in the library.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi You can use this code to upload files and check ether the file is successfully updated or not**

Code -

```html
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 

#Get Connection to the url via Connect-PnPOnline $URL

Connect-PnPOnline "Some SharePoint Url" -UseWebLogin

#store all the files in the folder(get files using get-ChildItem)
#for single file you can use something like : $file = LocalPath\fileName.txt
$Files = Get-ChildItem "Local Folder Path which contains the files"

#Looping through each item 
foreach($File in $Files){
    
#storing the add-pnpFile in a variable so that i will be able to know the status, if my file have been successfully uploaded or not.
#"Shared Documents\If inside shared document you want to give some folder it will come here" else only "Shared Document"
    
$upload = Add-PnPFile -Folder "Shared Documents\FolderToUpload" -Path $File.FullName
    
#now checking, if file successfully uploaded or not and printing the required message. (You can use Write-Host $message if you want to print the message)
    
    if($upload.UniqueId){
      $message = "Successfully Uploaded" 
    } 
    else {
        $message = "ERROR - Unable to Upload"
    }
 }
```